# Java Algorithm for finding the largest set of independent nodes in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

By independent nodes, I mean that the returned set can not contain nodes that are in immediate relations, parent and child cannot both be included. I tried to use Google, with no success. I don't think I have the right search words.

A link, any help would be very much appreciated. Just started on this now.

I need to return the actual set of independent nodes, not just the amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute this recursive function with dynamic programming (memoization):

```
MaxSet(node) = 1 if "node" is a leaf
MaxSet(node) = Max(1 + Sum{ i=0..3: MaxSet(node.Grandchildren[i]) },  
                       Sum{ i=0..1: MaxSet(node.Children[i])      })
```

The idea is, you can pick a node or choose not to pick it. If you pick it, you can't pick its direct children but you can pick the maximum set from its grandchildren. If you don't pick it, you can pick maximum set from the direct children.

If you need the set itself, you just have to store how you selected "Max" for each node. It's similar to the [LCS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

This algorithm is O(n). It works on trees in general, not just binary trees.

Comment: This computes the size of the largest set, not the set itself.

Comment: I need to return the actual node's, not just max. I will edit my post.

Comment: Edited to compute the actual set.

Comment: This looks really nice, but this is really advanced. Sum and max I haven't seen before, and I don't directly see how I would store the value to retrieve the set?

Comment: i=0..3: MaxSet(node.Grandchildren[i])
i=0..1: MaxSet(node.Children[i]) Could you or someone explain this bit for me?

Comment: data_jepp: It's not a standard notation, of course. I couldn't type a sigma there :) `Max` simply gets the maximum of two items. You'd use a `HashMap` or add a field to your node class that stores whether you select the node, or choose to select its children.

Comment: `MaxSet` is the function you are declaring, by the way. It's a simple dynamic programming problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: Im so sorry, I still dont get the i's. Why 0..3 and 0..1?

Comment: The index doesn't really matter. If you select a node, you can select all its grand children (at most 4, thus 0..3). If you don't, you can select its direct children (at most 2, thus 0..1).

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But how would you do the actually storing of the nodes. Lets say the set is an ArrayList, were in the code above would I add an independent node to the independent set?

Comment: In the algorithm, you'll just mark the operand you selected as max for each node. When the whole thing is done, you start at the root and check the direction you should go (it'll tell you whether you should add the root node to the list or not). It also tells you what nodes you should visit afterwards (if selected, you'll do the same thing recursively on grandchildren, otherwise you'll do it on children).

Comment: If I need to run trough it again the running time for finding the independent set would be more than O(n)? Thank you for helping me out here, I'm really appreciating this.

Comment: No. It won't be. You'll be visiting **at most** `n` nodes in the second pass. It'll be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I would take-and-remove all leaves first while marking their parents as not-to-take, then remove all leaves that are marked until no such leaves are left, then recurse until the tree is empty.  I don't have a proof that this always produces the largest possible set, but I believe it should.

Comment: Ah, you kinda go every other height level from the bottom towards the root? Not bad! I'll implement it and see.

Comment: The leaves do not need to be at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100696/1941755) to a question for the same problem, although the solution is in python, the explanation, algorithm, and test cases could be applicable.